# How to create, Bitmap transformation to add effect like snapchat ones?

Tags: javascript, android, image-processing, effects, snapchat

I'm looking into hint or way to achieve the same result in attached pic [image: Big Smile effect]

Native android or JavaScript is most welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more specific in you questioning? I think your mean something deforming a face, but is it real-time or after taking the photo?

Maybe this answer helps your out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830963/1783311

Comment: Yeah Exactly, I want it in after taking photo as first step .

Comment: You might check out https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera also could you mark my answer as "answer"?